# Wordpress disable private posts links

Tags: wordpress, private, posts

I have a website of sports competitions. I can create the calendars of future matches, and then I set the post status to "private".

Users that are *NOT* logged in can click on the post and access it.

How can I disable the link to the post for users not logged in?

Comment: Hey,You just put check like is_user_logged_in() ;

Comment: Private is your category?

Comment: Erick G. "Is this sentence mistake,NOT logged in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code inside your function.php file.

```
function getPrivatePostMatch()
{
    global $post;
    $status = get_post_status( $post->ID );
    if( $status == "private" )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );  // you can add your page url here
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','getPrivatePostMatch');
```

Comment: Do you think `wp_redirect` will work on `the_content` filter ?

Comment: then post your answer please

Comment: is already a very good solution, it would be perfect if you could display a dialog box maybe a java call "The match has not been played"

Comment: If you have better solution please share with us.